# Javascript array and object comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to store the max and min temperature of a year.

So I've got an array and an object like this.

```
var Months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];  

result[0] = {January: 26.2, February: 25.9, March: 25.7, April: 23.4, May: 19.3, June: 15.9, July: 15.4, August: 16, September: 21.3, October: 24.8, November: 26.6, December: 26.6,Type: "Min"}

result[1] = {January: 36.3, February: 35.9, March: 36, April: 36.7, May: 34.2, June: 31.4, July: 32, August: 34, September: 37.8, October: 39.5, November: 39.8, December: 37.8,Type: "Max"}.
```

This is the data I have and now I want two different arrays that store data in a proper order. (From Jan - Dec)

For example:

```
var min = [26.2,25.9,25.7,23.4,19.3,15.9,15.4,16,21.3,24.8,26.6,26.6]
var max = [36.3,35.9,36,36.7,34.2,31.4,32,34,37.8,39.5,39.8,37.8]
```

How can I extract that data from the object and make sure the order is the same with the "Months"? Also I need to remove the "Type" of Min/Max in my new arrays.

Comment: And the problem is? Iterate over the months and use them to extract the values from the objects...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use **[`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to map the relevant month values from your `result` objects and assign them to your `min` and `max` variables.

This is how should be your code:

```
var [min, max] = result.map(r => Months.map(m => {
  return r[m]
}));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var Months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var result = [];


result[0] = {January: 26.2, February: 25.9, March: 25.7, April: 23.4, May: 19.3, June: 15.9, July: 15.4, August: 16, September: 21.3, October: 24.8, November: 26.6, December: 26.6,Type: "Min"};

result[1] = {January: 36.3, February: 35.9, March: 36, April: 36.7, May: 34.2, June: 31.4, July: 32, August: 34, September: 37.8, October: 39.5, November: 39.8, December: 37.8,Type: "Max"};

var [min, max] = result.map(r => Months.map(m => {
  return r[m]
}));

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any loop. Simply use `Object.values()` and `pop()` so that the last element is removed from array which is `Type` value.

```js
var Months  = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];  

var result = [{January: 26.2, February: 25.9, March: 25.7, April: 23.4, May: 19.3, June: 15.9, July: 15.4, August: 16, September: 21.3, October: 24.8, November: 26.6, December: 26.6,Type: "Min"},
 {January: 36.3, February: 35.9, March: 36, April: 36.7, May: 34.2, June: 31.4, July: 32, August: 34, September: 37.8, October: 39.5, November: 39.8, December: 37.8,Type: "Max"}];
 
 var min = Object.values(result[0]);
 min.pop();
 var max = Object.values(result[1]);
 max.pop();
 console.log(min);
 console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ordered elements of the `months` array to sequentially access the appropriate month keys of each `result` object. Since your months array doesn't include a `Type` element, that key will be ignored.

```js
var Months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var result = []
result[0] = {January: 26.2, February: 25.9, March: 25.7, April: 23.4, May: 19.3, June: 15.9, July: 15.4, August: 16, September: 21.3, October: 24.8, November: 26.6, December: 26.6,Type: "Min"}
result[1] = {January: 36.3, February: 35.9, March: 36, April: 36.7, May: 34.2, June: 31.4, July: 32, August: 34, September: 37.8, October: 39.5, November: 39.8, December: 37.8,Type: "Max"}

var min = []
var max = []

for (let month of Months) {
  min.push(result[0][month])
  max.push(result[1][month])
}

console.log(min, max)
```